# Failing table creation using SymmetricDS and Oracle master DB

Tags: symmetricds

We have following setup:

- Multiple clients with MySQL 8.x, each

  - One schema for SymmetricDS
  - Multiple schemas containing (source) tables to be synced.
- One master with an Oracle 12.2

  - One Service which contains SymmetricDS tables AND the (target) tables to be synced.

So it looks like:

Client: Schema/Service : qwerz; Table: table_a

Master: Schema/Service: dabc_svc.tst.tns; Table: table_a

Our router looks like this:

INSERT INTO  SYM_ROUTER (router_id, target_catalog_name,
        source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('client2master', 'dabc_svc.tst.tns','abc_client', 'abc_central',
        current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

The trigger:

insert into sym_trigger
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name, source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('trigger_a','qwertz','*','default',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

If I trigger now an initial load with:

insert into SYM_TABLE_RELOAD_REQUEST (target_node_id, source_node_id, trigger_id, router_id, create_time, create_table, last_update_time)
     values ('master', 'client_a', 'ALL', 'ALL', current_timestamp, 1, current_timestamp);

SymmetricDS tries to create the tables on Oracle with a statement like this:
CREATE TABLE "dabc_svc.tst.tns"."SYM_USER"."TABLE_A" (...);

Which fails with the error “missing or invalid options” on Oracle. 
It looks to me like the create table statement is wrong, because executing manually CREATE TABLE “TABLE_A" (...); works just fine.

Do I overlook something?

Comment: Do you have SYM_ROUTER.USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA set to 1?  If so, try setting it to 0 so the catalog and schema aren 't used to create the table.